# UIScrollView Zooming

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Hi
I have taken a uiscrollview in xib IBOUTLET and have added a subview uitextview, and in that textview, have done horizontal scrolling since there are some contents to be displayed . i just need to do one thing that when user zoom in textview it should zoom , like when user touches two finger , it should have zooming gesture and zoom the content i have tried a lot however it didn't work. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Put a UITextView object into a UIScrollView object, and make the uitextview larger than the scrollView.

Also set property
scrollView.contentSize = textView.frame.size;
should be placed in the scrollViewDidEndZooming delegate

Comment: how can we put uitextview object into a uiscrollview object

Comment: [scrollView addSubview:textView];